# How to solve differential equation $y'+\frac xy=x^2y^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried to let $u=y^2$, and got
$$u'+2x=2x^2u^2,$$
but I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ODE of the Riccati kind which solution involves Bessel functions :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't expected it's that difficult, your answer is wonderful.